# Dispatching events, IE9, SVG and CSS pointer events

Tags: javascript, css, svg, dom-events

I have SVG layer on top of div, and I would like to dispatch events from SVG to div layer that has contenteditable set to true resulting thus in div having a focus.

Here is html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="div1" contenteditable="true" style="width:100px; height:100px; border:solid 1px red; position:absolute; left:0; top:0;">
    </div>
    <svg height="100" version="1.1" width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="position: absolute;left:50px; top:0; border:2px solid blue;pointer-events:none;" id="raphaelCanvasSvg"><desc></desc><defs/></svg>
</body>
</html>
```

I've noticed that if underlying div contain text I don't need to dispatch events, otherwise I do.

Here is graphical representation:

[image]

otherwise:

[image]

Is it possible to dispatch events even if user click on part where there is no text beneath?

Edit:
To further clarify my question, is it possible to get same behavior in IE9 as with Firefox or Chrome with following fiddle:
[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krul/wP7sK/8/)